# How to use Sql Server Database Publishing Wizard to make a schema with NO DATA?

Tags: sql-server, databasepublishingwizard

I can't seem to figure out how to get it to create a script that does not also include all the data, for creating an empty shell of the database. Or will I have to manually remove all the INSERTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I figured it out: at the end there is a drop down where you select "Schema and Data", "Schema Only", or "Data Only".